# Resampling step for MC variation reduction

Tags: localization, algorithm, particle-filter

I am reading particle filtering for robot localisation and specifically the resampling step to avoid particle degeneracy.  Can anyone explain me what MC (Monte Carlo) variation means? I saw it couple of times as a benefit of some resampling techniques against others.

For example, "Systematic resampling is the scheme preferred by the authors [since it is simple to implement, takes O(N) time, and minimizes the MC variation]" (Arulampalam et al., 2002).

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, George. It looks like you copied a line from the paper, "[A Tutorial on Particle Filters for Online Nonlinear/Non-Gaussian Bayesian Tracking](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa12/optreadings/Arulampalam_etal_2002.pdf)," by Arulampalam et al. The *full* quote mentions source [25] - "Systematic resampling [25] is the scheme preferred by the authors", where [25] is, “Monte Carlo filter and smoother for non-Gaussian nonlinear state space models,” by G. Kitagawa. I would, in general, highly suggest following the cited sources if you have questions.

Comment: This is still a good question, though. I'm hoping you get some great answer! :)